# Using 1and1, heroku, www domain does not have ssl

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I have a website hosted on heroku. I purchased hobby and now it has ssl. On 1and1 I point root domain to https:// address and ssl works fine. On www domain there is no ssl. I added ssl herokudn address to CNAME for www subdomain on 1and1. Does not work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Rails. On production.rb you must uncomment `config.force_ssl = true`